# I can't figure out how to get the largest element in loop

Tags: kotlin

I don't understand the loop in the following content.

```kotlin
There is a sequence of integer numbers (which ends with the number 0). Find the largest element of this sequence.

The number 0 itself is not included in the sequence. It serves only as a sign that there are no more numbers.
```

I tried various methods, but they did not solve the problem.

The  way to exit the loop at 0 is to use

```kotlin
While(i ! = 0){}
```

Here is the code we created.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var count = scanner.nextInt()

    do {
        var input = scanner.nextInt()
        while(input != 0 || count != 0) {
            if (count < input){
                count = input
            }
        }

    }while(input != 0 || count != 0)
    println(count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxOf()` for example:

```
 fun readLn() = readLine()!!
 fun readIntOrStopLoopWithZero() = readLn().toIntOrNull() ?: 0
 
 fun readMaxInteger() {
      var maxInput: Int = 0
      //getting first user input
      var userInput = readIntOrStopLoopWithZero()
 
     while (userInput!= 0) {
         //calc max
         maxInput = maxOf(userInput, maxInput)
         //getting user input again.
         userInput= readIntOrStopLoopWithZero()
     }
     if (maxInput == 0)
         //In case we get 0 as first input.
         print("max value not found")
     else
         print("Max input is : $maxInput")
 }
 readMaxInteger()
```

Input:

```
1
2
0
```

output:

```
Max input is 2
```

Input:

```
1
0
```

output:

```
Max input is 1
```

Input:

```
0
```

output:

```
max value not found
```

Input:

```
1
2
3
Word
```

output:

```
Max input is : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. You've over-complicated it by creating a nested loop.
2. You're checking `input != 0` to exit either of the loops, so it will exit immediately on the first element.

So fixing these problems, you have:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var count = 0 // start with 0 for simplicity

    do {
        val input = scanner.nextInt()
        if (count < input) {
            count = input
        }
    } while (input != 0)
    println(count)
}
```

And here's an alternate solution. Make a Sequence so it becomes an Iterable and you can use `maxOrNull()` on it:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val sequence = sequence {
        val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
        do {
            val input = scanner.nextInt()
            yield(input)
        } while (input != 0)
    }
    println(sequence.maxOrNull() ?: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to finish within a single function, so I chose the following.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)
    var count = 0 // start with 0 for simplicity

    do {
        val input = scanner.nextInt()
        if (count < input) {
            count = input
        }
    } while (input != 0)
    println(count)
}
```

Thanks to everyone who responded!